# В чём проблема моего кода? Как ее исправить?

Tags: javascript, discord, telebot

Это мой дискорд бот. Но как только начал добавлять в бота функционал он выдаёт ошибку...

помогите пожалуйста с проблемой

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const fs = require('fs');
let config = require('./botconfig.json');
let token = config.token;
let prefix = config.prefix;

fs.readdir('./cmd/',(err,files)=>{
    if(err) console.log(err);
    let jsfiles = files.filter(f => f.split(".").toUpperCase() === "js");
    if(jsfiles.length <=0) console.log("Нет комманд для загрузки!") ;
    console.log(`Загружено ${jsfiles.length} комманд`);
    jsfiles.forEach((f,i) =>{
        let props = require(`./cmd/${f}`);
        console.log(`${i+1}.${f} Загруден!`);
        bot.commands.set(props.help.name,props);
    })

})


bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Запустился бот ${bot.user.username}`) ;
  bot.generateInvite(["ADMINISTRATOR"]).then(link =>{
      console.log(link);
  })
});

bot.on('message', msg => {
    if(MessageChannel.author.bot) return;
    if(message.channel.type == "dm") return;
    let user = message.author.username;
    let userid = message.autor.id;
    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    let command = messageArray[0].toLoserCase();
    let args = messageArray.slice(1);
    if(message.content.startWith(prefix)) return;
    let cmd = bot.commands.get(command.slice(prefix.length))
    if(cmd) cmd.run(bot,message,args)
});

bot.login(token);
```

Ошибка:

```
PS C:\Users\fedtv\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\botDS> node bot.js
C:\Users\fedtv\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\botDS\bot.js:11
    let jsfiles = files.filter(f => f.split(".").UpperCase() === "js");
                                                 ^

TypeError: f.split(...).UpperCase is not a function
    at C:\Users\fedtv\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\botDS\bot.js:11:50
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\fedtv\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\botDS\bot.js:11:25
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:165:23)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`split` возвращает массив, а `UpperCase` это метод строки а не массива